# Replace all integers by 1?

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation

Let `list1` be a list of variables of the form `{c1 a, c2 b, ...}` where $a,b,...\in\mathbb{C}$ and $c1,c2,...\in\mathbb{Z}$. I am looking for a substitution rule to turn all the integers to `1` and just keep the variables in the list.

Example:

```
list1={3 a,4 b,-2 c,9 d};
```

Desired result:

```
list1/.Integers->1
```

> {a,b,c,d}

Please, let me know if there is a function that can do this. Or maybe it can be implemented in a way such that it works fast? Currently I am using the following workaround:

```
temp2 = list1; temp3 = temp2 /.a->1/.b->1/.c->1/.d->1;
Do[
  temp2[[ii]] = temp2[[ii]]/temp3[[ii]];
, {ii, 1, Dimensions[temp2][[1]]}];
```

But it becomes rather slow once the length of `list1` gets large (about 50 000 entries). Is there a way to speed things up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution depends on how you want a zero integer coefficient treated.

```
list1 = {0 v, 3 a, 4 b, -2 c, 9 d};

Variables[list1]
```

> {a, b, c, d}

```
list1 /. _Integer :> 1
```

> {1, a, b, c, d}

```
list1 /. x_Integer :> Unitize[x]
```

> {0, a, b, c, d}

Comment: Perfect! I just ran into an issue with zeros and your answer resolved the issues immediately. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like what you want is:

```
list1 /. {_Integer -> 1}
```

Comment: Ah, sniped me by a few seconds : )

Comment: @evanb -- Your explanation is better than mine though!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a pattern to just operate on the integers.

For example, `list1 /. _Integer -> 1` yields `{a,b,c,d}`.

Not sure if it's as fast as you need it.

Explanation:  the underscore `_` is an unnamed pattern and the attached `Integer` says that the pattern should only match things whose `Head` is `Integer`.  You can use other heads after the _, of course, to match different things...